# Multiple child creation with fork() in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, operating-system, fork

I want to create multiple children using `fork()`, but I am facing problems. 
LIKE:

```
///////////////////////// these are some class objects creation and calling
//  There are some functions calling from another class. about 5 functions I invoked.
// and some variables like.

    pid_t PID;
    int status = 0;
    char *x = new char[10];

///////////////////////// This for loop give me multiple children
// now one parent have multiple children in this case 10


    for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
    {
        mNo++;
        rNo++;
        PID = fork();

        if( PID == FORK_ERROR )         // fork ERROR!
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR! In fork() [FORCE EXITING]... %d\n", errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if( PID == CHILD )         // Do Child Stuff Here...
        {
            exit(status);
        }
        else            // Do parent Stuff Here...
        {

        }
    }
    PID = wait(&status);

////////////////////////////////////////////
```

This was my code which I implemented, but there are some problems.

I want to ask that when I create a child in memory, it creates the duplicate memory .  Also the objects which I declared; are they reinvoked by calling `fork()` so does that mean that for every child there are objects in memory which are reinvoked on class?

I want that if I fork, and the previous functions calling and variables should be same for every child but not non-idempotent functions. I hope you get it. I know this is a very simple problem, but the project I am working on is very critical and it has to implemented with `fork()`, not in pipes or threads.

Moreover, I am repeating my question that if I `fork()`, what happens to objects and variables. Before calling fork, are they just reallocated or they again reinvoked for every child?  But what I am seeing is that they are reinvoked for every child, which I don't want.  So what do I have to do?

Comment: Are you coding in C or C++?  Choose one or the other.

Comment: it's really hard to understand what you want or what is your problem.  what i'm guessing is that you don't want all your objects duplicated by the `fork()` copy-on-write behavior.  if so, `fork()` won't help you.  if you want to share objects you must use threads instead of processes.

Comment: What do you mean by "reinvoked"?

Comment: Ok. it is not a hard problem. but you are focusing. A BIG THANKS TO YOU. so, in my code there are objects creations and functions calling. the function invocations means that i am try some system resource like some file. Now, if the same memory is allocating. then why it prints multiple cout. which i wrote before fork. and why it is accessing my file again and again. on every child creation. I hope you understand well. Tell me where i am wrong. PLEASE HELP ME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) will not change to suit your wishes.

When the process forks, there are two almost identical copies of the same program.  The differences are listed in the POSIX manual page (link above).  The memory is the same.  Objects in C++ will not be re-constructed, for example.  In each of the processes, all the singletons will still be singletons, for example.

> Could you give me an example?

Here's the complete main program from something I wrote back in 1991.  I've only updated it to use a prototype for `main()` and I've included the typedef for `Pipe` and the definition of `id`:

```
static char id[] = "\n\n\nSQLMONITOR version 3.5 \n";
typedef int Pipe[2];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int     pid;
    Pipe    to_sqlexec;
    Pipe    from_sqlexec;

    setarg0(argv[0]);
    write(STDERR, id, sizeof(id)-1);
    if (pipe(to_sqlexec) < 0 || pipe(from_sqlexec) < 0)
        error("unable to create pipes");
    else if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        error("unable to fork");
    else if (pid == 0)
        be_childish(argv, to_sqlexec, from_sqlexec);
    else
        be_parental(to_sqlexec, from_sqlexec);
    return(0);
}
```

The `be_childish()` function went on to do some plumbing (duplicating and closing appropriate parts of the pipes, before executing another program.  The `be_parental()` process went on to read messages from its standard input, log them to a file, and write the messages to the standard input of its child down the write-side of the `to_sqlexec` pipe; it would then read a response back from the child on the read-side of the `from_sqlexec` pipe, and log that message too, and then write it to its standard output.  Thus, it would sit in the middle of two processes, recording everything that went from one to the other.  The communication protocol between the processes was synchronous, which greatly simplified life.  On the other hand, it was moderately hard to work out when the data from one process was complete.   The code predated the widespread availability of `select()` and `poll()`; nowadays, it would not need to do as much analysis of the messages.

The key thing to note, though, is that the two pipes are the same in both processes after the `fork()`; indeed, the only variable that's different is `pid` which captures the return value from `fork()`.  Everything else is exactly as it was before the `fork()`.

Comment: An example of what, precisely? In the child process, as in the parent process, all the variables that had been created will still exist...well, it gets more complicated with threaded applications since the child has but one thread where the parent may have had many, but threading is not a problem here. So, the child process returns from `fork()` receiving a value 0 as the return value; the parent returns from `fork()` receiving its child's PID.  What happens next depends on the code. In your case, your child seems to obliterate itself with `exit()`, while the parent goes on to breed some more.

Comment: OK.. in my case there is one ohter thing which is happening. i just cout before the for loop and on shell it prints multiple times the thing. which it should not print multiple times only have to print the parent and it should print only one time. is'nt it?. that doesn't sense me good. why is this.

Comment: Ah...buffered I/O and unflushed I/O...always good for some fun.  In C, you'd be advised to use `fflush(0)` to flush all pending I/O before you do `fork()`.  With C++, you should use `cout << endl;` probably, or something similar (my knowledge of the C++ I/O library is not as thorough as it could/should be).  If you don't flush before forking, both the child and the parent have output waiting to be written, so both the child and the parent eventually write the same information.  The child is an exact copy of the parent!

Answer (score 2):

When you fork, your child is a copy of the parent process, including the heap. Hence you have a separate copy of your objects or memory allocated using new. I am not sure what you mean by reinvoked but you are going to have 2 separate objects on 2 separate heaps in 2 separate processes if you had allocated an object using new() in the parent.
One would be the original one in the parent process and another a copy on the copied heap in the child process.

This will help understand better: [Linux fork within class on heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062991/linux-fork-within-class-on-heap)

Comment: Thanks. for you answer. by reading all the stuff on internet and searching. i have come to know that before fork what ever i have created what ever the state of program. after fork they will be as copied. as it should. and then what ever i want  to do with the copied data separately. and parallel. THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you don't know what fork() does. Which makes it seem odd that you're convinced it's the right function.

Read about it:

http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(operating_system)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29)

At a glance, it appears that child processes get a copy of the parent's memory.

Comment: THANKS, i know this code is doing what should it does. i want to know just a question that what happen to the objects and data. which i declared before fork. it want some thread working. using fork. Ok. what i want can i explain:

Comment: obj 1; obj 2, obj 3, obj1(); obj2(); obj3();

Comment: now i fork(). and do all the stuff of fork implemetation. what happen to the objects are they recalled for every child or not. i want they should not call on class again.

Comment: you get a copy of the memory in which those objects are stored. they are not re-allocated, or anything, just copies of memory. that is your child will have identical objects, but they'll use separate memory.

Comment: so can you tell me the exact way of creating multiple child . i want that one parent should have multiple child . and the objects on which i invoke functions. and all childs have the same copy and use them. can you tell me.

Comment: fork()ed children do not share memory. don't use fork() if you want them to share memory.

Comment: fork() is not a C++ thing. it doesn't operate on objects. It creates a new process, and instead of loading a binary off the disk, it gives this new process the exact state of the parent process, except for a few tiny details, as listed on the manual page.

Comment: then could you please tell me what is the exact way that one parent ahve multiple children. have variable children.

Answer (score 1):

If you fork, I think, all the objects and variables will be exactly the same as the parent process. I do not understand by "but whaat i am seeing that they are reinvoked for every child" what are reinvoked here?

Comment: reinvoked means that how i use a resource or object by using a function.